# Sulu's Daughter's Parentage?

Tags: character, star-trek, star-trek-the-original-series, star-trek-beyond

How is Hikaru Sulu's daughter related to him, in both the old and new timelines? Adopted? Surrogate? Gene spliced or other technological means? From an older relationship?

Comment: In the old timeline it seems rather clear (unless the filmmakers said the character change was retroactive). And in the new timeline we seem to be reliant to either explicit commentary on her parentage from the filmmakers, or possible future films (provided *Beyond* didn't adress it, which seems unlikely given your question).

Comment: Nope, the film makes no explicit reference to her in the script.

Comment: its sulu's since the original timeline had her as well, and he was straight in that timeline

Comment: @Himarm Well, still the question stands whose daughter she is in the timeline where he *isn't* straight anymore.

Comment: FYI: You actually broached the subject you wrote that you didn't want to broach and also added to the controversy by using judgemental language ("ignorant"). So, if you don't want the controversy to be brought up, you might want to edit your question. Just don't even mention that you're not even mentioning it. That's the best way to not mention something.

Comment: Does this cover the version in Generations as well? Or just Beyond?

Comment: @Thunderforge Generations is the Old Timeline, so yes.

Answer (score 3):

The official answer is, there is no official answer.

The biological relationship between Sulu and his daughter Demora is not specifically mentioned in either old or new timeline (although it is addressed in the non-canon old-timeline novel [The Captain's Daughter](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/The_Captain's_Daughter) as the result of a one-night-stand)